# Array strings C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I don't remember how to do this in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char categorias[3][20];
    /*char pais[3][20];
    char movimiento[3][50];
    char obras[100][50]; */

    categorias[0]="Alta";
    categorias[1]="Media";
    categorias[2]="Baja";
}
```

This throws this error: 19  15  C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Subasta.cpp   [Error] incompatible types in assignment of 'const char [5]' to 'char [20]';

Long time ago I don't use C++ and I can´t solve the problem.

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of `char[]` and your life will be much easier.

Comment: This isn't array of strings but array of characters. To copy to an array of characters use strcopy or something. Though, I advise to use `std::array<std::string,3> categorias` instead of `char[3][20]`.

Comment: Note that `Dev C++` is an IDE and not a compiler. I assume you are using some version of mingw.

Comment: `main(){` in `c++` you should not omit the `int` before `main`.

Comment: `categorias[0]="Alta";` c-strings are not assignable. Replace `char categorias[3][20];` with `std::string categorias[3];` and the assignment will work.

Answer (score 3):

Use C++ abstractions and containers from the standard library:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    auto categorias = std::vector{"Alta"s, "Media"s, "Baja"s};

    // Or if you know you have a fixed number of categories:
    auto categorias = std::array{"Alta"s, "Media"s, "Baja"s};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To copy the string literal into the char array

```
strcpy(categorias[0], "Alta");
```